# ¿Por qué migración en laravel no me crea una tercer tabla que es password_resets?

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos, tablas

buenas noches, les cuento que estoy iniciando laravel y estoy en base de datos viendo migraciones, pues les cuento que todo va bien pero salta error y no me crea la tabla password_resets que supuestamente deberia crearme, ¿a qué se debe?
Aquí les paso dos imagenes una para que vean en phpmyadmin que laravel solo me creó dos tablas y en otra lo que me salió en el cmd.

Y tambien configuré en el archivo .env de laravel todos los parámetros para conectarme con la base de datos y no he modificado nada de lo que laravel creó en cuestión de migraciones esos dos archivos que tiene:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=curso_styde
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

[image: Pongo el comando php artisan migrate pero solo me crea dos tablas y me da error]

[image: Aquí vemos que solo me crea dos tablas]

Gracias amigos, espero sus ayudas.

Comment: La migracion esta tirando un error. buscate algo respecto de ese error?

Comment: tienes una versión inferior a mysql 5.7 verdad?

Comment: 10.1.35-MariaDB    eso me sale amigo al seleccionar select @@version jeje

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUCIÓN 1**

Para solucionar ese error, debes ir a tu `AppServiceProvider.php` y dentro del método `boot()` agregar lo siguiente

La ubicación de dicho archivo es: **nombreProyecto/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php**

```
Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
```

**SOLUCIÓN 2**

Instalar una versión mas reciente de mysql, de preferencia de mysql 5.7 en adelante o mariaDB 10.2 o 10.3 preferentemente

Si estas usando Laravel en una versión 5.5 o superior posterior a alguna de las 2 soluciones que te estoy dando, basta que ejecutes

```
php artisan migarte:fresh
```

El comando anterior borrará todas tus tablas y ejecutará todas las migraciones de nuevo.

Este detalle se presenta por que desde la versión de Laravel 5.4 el `character_set`es `UTF8MB4` entonces versiones de mysql inferiores por ejemplo a mysql 5.7 no lo soportan y por eso marca el error

Comment: hola amigo gracias por responder pero causaria algun problema problema posteriormente al realizar la solucion 1 ?

Comment: esta bien lo voy a hacer estoy intentando vas a disculpar pero recien inicio en esto y estoy buscando el AppServiceProvider.php jkajajaja

Comment: que bien amigo me funciono muchas gracias ya me creo todo y no me tiro error pero a q se debio el problema? es un bug de laravel? o que posiblemente pude haber hecho yo mal ? y bueno pues como te tickeo para que obtengas puntos de stackoverflow jajaja. gracias

Comment: ya estuvo gracias.